# Is there a reason why Sci Fi Australia wouldn't get the broadcast licenses for Star Trek: Deep Space Nine?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, tv, star-trek-voyager

In Australia, the Foxtel (Pay TV) Channel SciFi (ch 123) has been airing repeats of *Star Trek: The Next Generation* and *Star Trek: Voyager*. while not strange by itself what gets me is that *The Next Generation* first aired in 1987 and *Voyager* first aired in 1995 and there's been no mention on SciFi about *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* which was aired in 1993, before *Voyager*

I know the age of the series isn't a problem as SciFi currently started airing *Quantum Leep* which first aired in 1989 which is only a couple of years younger than *The Next Generation* but also a few months back the original TV series of *The Hitch Hikers Guide to the Galaxy* which first aired in 1981 was aired on SciFi and that's obviously older.

Also when *The Next Generation* first aired on SciFi *Voyager* was announced during *The Next Generation* Season and it only just started it first re-run before *Voyager* took it's timeslot. currently however *Voyager* is on it's 3rd re-run.

So I am wondering, is there a reason why Sci Fi Australia wouldn't get the broadcast licenses for *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, even though they did for *The Next Generation* and *Voyager*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like DS:9 is on [Netflix in Australia](https://newonnetflix.com/australia/movie/483864/star-trek%3A-deep-space-nine-season-3). So it might be as simple as losing out on bidding for the rights.

If you want a more exciting conspiracy theory; DS:9 is the only Star Trek from the first four, older series, that really goes in for Myth Arcs. Generally everything in TOS, ST:NG and VOY is one and done episodic TV. Australia Sci-Fi so underestimate their audience, that they think they can't hack remembering what happened three episodes ago.

Comment: It's definitely on Netflix here in Australia, I was watching it when I came across this question :)

Comment: Maybe they prefer B5 :P

Comment: Or maybe the australian stations realize that people who want to watch star trek aren't into "soap operas in space" where you follow the daily lives of the characters.  I prefer episodes where the author has a point to make, and something to say over watching the soap opera of Odo and Kiera falling in love.